# Issue with loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that already works and looks like this:

```
tolerance=5
def pmm_rag(data):

    if  ((data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'AIR') & (data.latedeliverydate < data.m6plan)):
        return 'R'

    elif ((data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'AIR') & (data.m6_event >= data.m6plan)):
        return 'G'

    elif ((data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'AIR') & (data.m6_event >= data.m6plan)):
        return 'A'

    else:
        return ''
```

I want to add on my function 2 conditions but it's not populating the result:

```
def pmm_rag(data):

    while data.m2 == '' is False:

        if  ((data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'AIR') & (data.m6_event < data.m6plan)):
            return 'R'

        elif ((data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'AIR') & (data.m6_event >= data.m6plan)):
            return 'G'

        elif ((data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'AIR') & (data.m6_event >= data.m6plan)):
            return 'A'


    while data.m2 == '' is False:

        if  ((data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'AIR') & (data.latedeliverydate < data.m6plan)):
            return 'R'

        elif ((data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'AIR') & (data.latedeliverydate >= data.m6plan)):
            return 'G'

        elif ((data.SHIPMENT_MOT_x == 'AIR') & (data.latedeliverydate >= data.m6plan)):
             return 'A'

    else:
        return ''
```

Actually I want to introduce a while that loops over the rows that has `m2` and those that have not ?
How will I do that ?

Comment: It's not working is not an explanation, are you getting any errors ? If so what are those errors? If not what makes you think it is not working?

Comment: it returns nothing actually

Comment: By `data.m2 == '' is False`  you mean when `data.m2` is not empty? Then woudn't `while data.m2` suffice?

Comment: yes that's the statement there

Comment: Lastly do you intend to have same conditions in both loop?

Comment: yes thats what i want

Comment: don't use `&` for multiple conditions use `and`

Comment: And the whole while loop is not modifying `data` then you can just use `if` instead of `while`. Also your question mentioned two opposite condition. So `if`-`else` will suffice I guess

Comment: `data.m2 == '' is False` has priority/chaining issues

Comment: i tried the and without success...
this is the error i was havin: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
The & works fine

Comment: @Haalanam, sorry but your requirement is not clear to me. Can you elaborate? Also what error you get when tried with `if`-`else`?

Comment: Actually i am not receiving any error ...
My field was not populated when i call the function

Comment: @Haalanam, then can you please update your attempt with `if`-`else` in the question? That way it would be easier to point out the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use as your condition.

```
if data.m2 != '':
```

If you want to loop over the element of data.m2 you should use a "for" statement:

```
for x in data.m2:
```

Comment: `if data.m2 != '':` => `if data.m2:`

Comment: Isn't there a difference between an empty string and a null object ?

Comment: if all data.m2 are strings, no.